# ¿Cómo devolver una lista de ocurrencias dado un rango de fechas en Django Restframework?

Tags: django

Tengo un modelo llamado Ocurrencia que tiene una fecha de inicio y una fecha de fin, ambas de tipo DateTimeField. Estoy usando **Django Restframework** y he creado un viewset para mis ocurrencias, donde necesito redefinir el metodo list() para devolver todas las ocurrencias en un rango de fechas.

Quisiera saber como le puedo enviar o especificar al metodo list() los valores del rango de fecha, o sea la fecha de inicio y la fecha de fin. Esos valores llegarian por el request, por *args o **kwargs?

Abajo les dejo un ejemplo del viewset de Ocurrencia

```
class OcurrenciaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Ocurrencia.objects.all()
    serializer_class = OcurrenciaSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        lista = Ocurrencia.objects.filter(fechaInicio = fecha_inicio, fechaFin = fecha_fin)
        return lista
```

Donde fechaInicio y fechaFin son los atributos de Ocurrencia, y fecha_inicio y fecha_fin son los valores que necesito obtener en el list() para devolver las fechas segun un rango. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django te proporciona un `lookup` para poder hacer esa consulta, lo que debes definir es como quieres enviar los datos para que el servidor los trate, usualmente cuando se trata de listar, se utiliza el método GET de una petición, es decir, mandar los datos por la url, y a partir de ahí filtrar.

```
def list(request, *args, **kwargs):
    from django.utils import timezone
    # te debo, averiguar si al enviar parametros por la url
    # estos se almacenan en kwargs, como no estoy seguro,
    # lo haré de esta forma

    queryset = Ocurrencia.objects.all()

    fecha_inicial = request.GET.get('fecha_inicial')
    fecha_final = request.GET.get('fecha_final')

    def convert_to_datetime(date_string):
        # hay otras formas de hacer esto, con la librería datetime
        # puedes buscar como transformar un string a datetime, yo te propongo esta solución pero no es la mejor
        day, month, year = date_string.split('-')
        return datetime.datetime(day=day, month=month, year=year)

    # aquí deberías hacer validaciones, como, si hay ambas fechas, o que
    # la fecha final no sea menor a la fecha inicial, y etc
    if fecha_inicial and fecha_final:
       fecha_inicial = convert_to_datetime(fecha_inicial)
       fecha_final = convert_to_datetime(fecha_final)
       queryset = queryset.filter(fechaIncial__gte=fecha_inicial, fechaFin__lte=fecha_final)

    return queryset
```

Con los `lookup` de `gte` (Mayor o igual que) y `lte` (Menor o igual que), lo que hacemos es buscar ocurrencias que la fecha inicial sea mayor o igual a la fecha que viene en la url, y que tengan fecha de inicio menor o igual a la fecha que viene de la url, otra cosa importante, es que escogí un formato de fecha tal que `'11-10-2017'` es decir `'%D-%M-%YY'` si quieres otro formato deberás hacer modificaciones al código. Lo ideal es hacer la consulta a una url como esta `http://tudominio.com/?fecha_inicial=14-08-1997&fecha_final=11-10-2017`.

Espero haberte ayudado, hay varias formas de hacer tu consulta, otra sería con el `lookup` que se llama `range`, pero no se exactamente como quieres filtrar con esos campos, por lo cual no te lo expliqué. Cualquier duda, comenta.

Comment: con esta implementación me va a retornar o filtrar todos los datos que corresponden por ejemplo al mismo día es decir: fecha_inicial=01-02-2018 & fecha_final=01-02-2018